# Why does assigning to a previously typed variable change its type?

Tags: typescript

Line 3 below shows that `foo` has type `"a"|"b"`, and on line 7 we're allowed to compare `foo` with `"b"`:

```
1 let foo: "a"|"b";
2 
3 // error: Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
4 foo = "c";
5 
6 switch (foo) {
7     case "b": break; // legal comparison
8 }
```

That's all exactly what I expect.

However, if I assign the value "a" to `foo`, that *changes the type of `foo`*, so that the comparison with `"b"` is no longer valid:

```
1 let foo: "a"|"b";
2 
3 // this line changes the type of foo to '"a"', rather than '"a"|"b"'
4 foo = "a";
5 
6 switch (foo) {
7     // error: Type '"b"' is not comparable to type '"a"'
8     case "b": break; // illegal comparison!
9 }
```

What the heck is going on here? Why does assigning a legal value to a strongly typed variable change the variable's type?

Comment: Because the compiler now knows what type it will have.

Comment: What do you mean "type it *will* have"? It already *has* a type. It was given a type on line 1. That type is `"a"|"b"`. That's why line 4 in the first examples fails.

Comment: Yes, but TS is smart enough to figure out that the type has narrowed here.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but it still makes no sense to me that it would work that way. For instance, rather than type `"a"|"b"`, say I had the type `enum Foo {a,b}`.  If I say `let foo = Foo.a`, I expect the type of `foo` to be `Foo`, not `Foo.a`.  Apparently doesn't work that way, but it's hyper-non-intuitive, coming from... any other typed language.  The enum *type* is `Foo`, while `Foo.a` should be an enum *value*.

Comment: It is indeed different from most languages, but actually I'd say TS is more powerful here even. Most languages don't even have literal types.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, TypeScript infers types based on usage. It's also worth noting that it only does this for Union types i.e. Type1|Type2

You can think of an inferred type as a 'Point In Time' type.

```
let foo: "a"|"b";
foo = 'a'; // foo has inferred type 'a' but actual type is still 'a'|'b'
foo = 'b'; // We can still assign 'b', foo now has inferred type 'b'
```

In your example, you got:

```
// error: Type '"b"' is not comparable to type '"a"'
```

This is because, at this point in time, TypeScript *knows* that `foo` is of type `'a'` and not type `'b'` so it updates the typing for you.

Another example is when you are creating a union between fairly different types:

```
let foo: string | number;
let bar: any = 'b';

foo = bar; // foo is now 'b' but has type string | number

foo.charAt(0); // Error: Property 'charAt' does not exist on type 'string | number' 

foo = 'a'; // foo now has inferred type of string

foo.charAt(0); // Can use string functions

foo = 24.123; // inferred type of number

foo.toFixed(0);
```

By narrowing/inferring the type, we can now use properties that are only available on one of the unioned types.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript infers types based on usage, described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html

So in your case it was using the common type until you assigned a value, when Typescript's contextual type algorithm kicked in.